# ListPlot takes too long with ColorFunction

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, color, data

I have about 200000 points, using `ListPlot` with  `ColorFunction` takes too long. Here is a minimal example with 5000 points which takes 7 sec.

```
dataA = Get[
   "https://www.dropbox.com/s/kf9ojjoe9na0rft/data.dat?dl=1"];
```

this is a custom color

```
colF[arg_] := Blend[{Gray, Blue}, Rescale[arg, {0, 1}]]
```

and visualizing the data as

```
ListPlot[dataA[[All, 1 ;; 2]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y}, 
    colF[dataA[[Position[dataA[[All, 1]], x][[1, 1]], 
       3]]]]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

However, without coloring, it takes 0.1 sec

```
ListPlot[dataA[[All, 1 ;; 2]]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: You are calling `Position` for every point in the list. This causes $O(n^2)$ time complexity for the plot, where $n$ is the length of the list.

There are multiple options which you could employ, but one I'd suggest would be ditching `ColorFunction` and using `Style` on each item, which should, if I understand your code correctly, avoid the need for `Position`.

Comment: `ListPlot[Style[{#1, #2}, colF[#3]] & @@@ dataA]` should accomplish the same task as your code with `ColorFunction`, but interestingly there seems to be a scalability issue in styled `ListPlot`. I'll probably write a bug report on this...

Comment: @kirma, I tried that but it takes a long time too.

Comment: Oh wow, interestingly enough `ColorFunction` is actually *a lot* more efficient that `Style`. So, my advice is actually not that great (apart from getting rid of repeated `Position` calls).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Removing the repeated calls of `Position` on `ColorFunction` and replacing them with use of a precomputed dispatch table improves performance quite a bit:

```
With[{color = Dispatch[#1 -> colF[#3] & @@@ dataA]},
  ListPlot[dataA[[All, 1 ;; 2]],
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x /. color]]] //
 AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: Both solutions are amazing, but I will accept the one with ListPlot

Answer (score 10):

`Graphics`is factor 20 faster than ListPlot in this example:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5000, 3}];
Graphics[Map[{Blend[{Gray, Blue}, Rescale[#[[3]], {0, 1}]],Point@Most[#]} &, data] ] // AbsoluteTiming 
(* {.027,...}*)
```